# failed to mod a module in Rust

Tags: rust, compiler-errors, rust-cargo

**here is my project structure:**

```
.
├── Cargo.toml
└── src
    ├── allocator.rs
    ├── config.rs
    ├── fs.rs
    ├── lib.rs
    └── main.rs

2 directories, 6 files
```

**my code:**

```
// src/lib
mod allocator;
use allocator::*;
// src/allocator
pub fn function(){

}
```

**and then compile failed:**

```
error[E0583]: file not found for module `allocator`
  --> pkg/boot/src/lib.rs:23:1
   |
23 | mod allocator;
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = help: to create the module `allocator`, create file "pkg/boot/src/lib/allocator.rs" or "pkg/boot/src/lib/allocator/mod.rs"
   = note: if there is a `mod allocator` elsewhere in the crate already, import it with `use crate::...` instead
```

I have tried the suggested solutions, but it still failed. I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: How did you crate `allocator.rs` file? If you did it inside some code editor, then maybe you didn't save it to disk. Are you sure this file exists outside your editor? Because rust cannot find it.

Comment: @AlexanderKrauze the file is there, but Rust is looking for `src/__lib__/allocator.rs` because OP included `mod lib;` somewhere in their code (unfortunately that bit is not in their example so it's not a [mre]).

Comment: @cafce25 thanks,it can work after I delete `mod lib`.I will pay more attention to asking better questions in the future.